# Which lightweight database should I use in a Firefox extension?

Tags: database, firefox

I currently use a flat-file to store data in a Firefox Extension, but think this is inadequate.

**Which lightweight databases are commonly used within Firefox extensions?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[SQLite is built in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Storage) to recent versions of Firefox for use as a data-storage mechanism. More information, and examples of how to use the FF wrapper API, can be found on [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Storage).

Answer (score 1):

sqlite, used be ff itself